# How to install nodejs application in godaddy vps server?

Tags: node.js, hosting

I have successfully run node.js application in my local system.Now i want to host my application in godaddy vps hosting.It is the centos server then how do install and run node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have this problem in GoDaddy and their support is not good at least for technical things. but that is just for sharing. if you going with VPS then this is like home PC in GoDaddy infrastructure. so that will not have the problem. second, this is based on the server os. may be you are using centOS. so [link](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-install-node-js-and-npm-on-centos/)

that work for me. 
second and most important that nodeJs are not that type of application that has to be there in root so if you have something problem in permission then you can download and work nodeJs anywhere you want. by just calling like 
/your path/node app.js or /your path/npm start